# Create a NuGet package with only javascript files

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I want to create a NuGet package that contains only javascript.  I have no assembly that needs to be built and included.

So to do this I created an empty solution in vs, and created an empty project.  In the project I created a Scripts directory with my javascript files.  I have a package.nuspec and a packages.config

When I run "nuget pack" commandline I get an error:

> C:\MyProject>nuget
>   pack 
>   Attempting to build package from 'TestProject.csproj'. 
>   MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.1.76.45076' from
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'.  
>   **Error NU5012: Unable to find 'C:\MyProject\TestProject.exe'. Make sure the project has been built.**
>   C:\MyProject>

If I try to build the project in visual studio,  I get an error...

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry
>   point.

...which makes sense because I made this from an empty project.

I am not trying to deploy the assembly, just javascript, can I stop it from trying to build somehow?

Comment: Are you able to create nuget package ? I am trying the same scenario with .ts files in a specific folder structure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a project. Have have your `.nuspec` and javascript files in the directory, then run `nuget pack`. If the `nuspec` doesn't contain a `<files>` section, then it will just copy the filesystem structure directly into the `nupkg`.

Having said that, new ASP.NET Core projects from Microsoft's templates no longer use front end resources (html, javascript, css) from NuGet packages, but rather use either [LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or npm, to be more in-line with what the non-.NET front-end ecosystem uses. I suggest investigating those technologies and using them if possible.